# Sass "failed to @extend" error -- can't extend imported css class

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

### jsbin demo of the error

http://jsbin.com/xurufa/2/edit?html,css,output

```
Line 4: ".testIcon" failed to @extend ".fa"
```

### the .scss file:

```
@import "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.css";
  
.testIcon {
  @extend .fa, .fa-camera-retro;
}
```

### the html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="description" content="Admin Site CSS">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  
</head>
<body>
  
<i class="testIcon"></i>

</body>
</html>
```

The `.fa` and `.fa-camera-retro` classes are being successfully imported, as you can verify by commenting out the `@extend` line and changing the html to:

```
<i class=".fa .fa-camera-retro"></i>
```

### question

given that classes exist, i'd like to know what the `@extend` isn't working, and how I can make it work?

Comment: Interested in this question too. Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Download the file, change the extension to SCSS/SASS then import the same or you can also use scss files come the download